# bootstrap 5 with jquery, How do you enable\disable and deselectall multiselect based on option in a different multiselect

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc, bootstrap-5

I have 2 multiselect dropdown lists one controlling the other and if a specific option is selected in the primary the secondary ddl is enabled.  I have this working.  The problem I'm having is if the user deselects the option that controls the secondary ddl and I try to deselectall then disable the secondary ddl the primary's selected option remains and the secondary is disabled but the selected options remain.

```
            $('#ddlCountry').on('change', function () {
                if ($('#ddlCountry option[value=620]:selected').length > 0) {
                    $('#ddlCities').multiselect('enable');
                } else {
                    $('#ddlCities"').multiselect('deselectAll', false);
                    $('#ddlCities').multiselect('disable');
                }
            });
```

Comment: It's confused for your description now, could you please provide a details example which contains the html and js which could easily reproduce it at our side. Then we could easily help you.

Comment: The code I'm working with is proprietary but I'll try to get a full example posted later, thanks